# Spring @Scheduled cron fixed time doesn't work with OS suspension

Tags: java, spring, windows-10, spring-scheduled

I have a Java app running in windows 10 environment, it uses Spring 6 library and in particular @Scheduler annotation with a cron expression to run a process at midnight.

This process worked for a few but we have experienced an issue, the schedulation has been called in a completely wrong time of the day, it was 9.37am instead of midnight.

After few investigations I discovered that before the issue the computer has been suspended, so it looks like the scheduler doesn't work with the OS suspension.
Is it possible? Is it an known problem?

Comment: Well if a computer is suspended, it won't run application code and eill continue after it's resumed (unless the scheduling would somehow tell Windowsto automatically resume which is typically not practical). What did you expect?

Comment: It sounds like the computer resumed at or around 9:37 and then resumed its work, as it should. If you don't want it to suspend, then you should configure the power management options of the machine to not suspend in a period of inactivity. The scheduler basically schedules task at or after time X. That X was at midnight, but as the machine wasn't running at that time, it will pick up where it left off once it's running again. Tasks which should have been run during that time the computer was suspended are then run to catch up.

Comment: I expected that the schedulation would had been skipped, like the computer was turned off at midnight. For sure I did not expect a running schedulation at wrong time. I think a Linux cron job would have done the same.